# After updating to Xubuntu 13.04, Brasero will not work, can this be remedied?

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, brasero

After updating to Xubuntu 13.04, Brasero will not work, does anyone else have this problem and can it be solved?

Comment: What error message appear when you start brasero in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If the Problem is Brasero stucking in the normalize process: This is a known bug reintroduced in 13.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/374101.

To workaround, start Brasero and go to 'Edit' → 'Plugins' and deactivate the normalize plugin.